# How to unittest that a thread is spawned?

Tags: python, multithreading, mocking

I have a race condition in a unittest I'm trying to fix.

Suppose there's a module `spam.py`:

```
import threading

def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def bar():
    t = threading.Timer(0.5, foo, args=('potato',), kwargs={'x': 69, 'y':'spam'})
    t.start()
```

And here is the test for it:

```
from mock import patch
from spam import bar
from unittest import TestCase

class SpamTest(TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        with patch('spam.foo') as mock:
            bar()
            mock.assert_called_once_with('potato', y='spam', x=69)
```

Of course this test fails with `AssertionError: Expected to be called once. Called 0 times.` because the call to `bar()` is non-blocking, so the assertion happens too early.

The test can be made to pass by putting a `time.sleep(1)` in before the assert, but this is obviously hacky and lame - what is the accepted way to mock / unittest asynchronous stuff?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about modifying the `bar` to return a thead object:

```
def bar():
    t = threading.Timer(0.5, foo, args=('potato',), kwargs={'x': 69, 'y':'spam'})
    t.start()
    return t # <----
```

Then, join the thread in the test code:

```
class SpamTest(TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        with patch('spam.foo') as mock:
            t = bar()
            t.join() # <----
            mock.assert_called_once_with('potato', y='spam', x=69)
```

**UPDATE** alternative that does not require `bar` change.

```
import threading
import time

...

class SpamTest(TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        foo = threading.Event()
        with patch('spam.foo', side_effect=lambda *args, **kwargs: foo.set()) as mock:
            # Make the callback `foo` to be called immediately
            with patch.object(threading._Event, 'wait', time.sleep(0.000001)):
                bar()
            foo.wait() # Wait until `spam.foo` is called. (instead of time.sleep)
            mock.assert_called_once_with('potato', y='spam', x=69)
```

**UPDATE**

In Python 3.x, patch `threading.Event` instead of `threading._Event`.

Comment: Interesting idea... but it seems a bit intrusive, and I don't like that it increases the runtime of the test code (e.g. what if I wanted to wait 1 hour before calling foo? It feels like the tests should have some sort of mock clock intsead)

Comment: @wim, I updated the answer to add an alternative way.

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason why you choose to patch `threading._Event`?  Tried with `patch.object(foo, 'wait')` instead and it seems to work too, without accessing that _attribute.

Comment: @wim, Measure both `patch.object(foo, 'wait')` and `patch.object(threading._Event, 'wait')`.

Comment: It should be noted, this solution doesn't work in Python 3.x. The solution @wim suggests does though.

Comment: @BradPitcher, What do you mean `solution @wim suggests`? **UPDATE** part of my answer?

Comment: @falsetru I mean `patch.object(foo, 'wait')`. Python 3.x gives an `AttributeError` on `threading._Event`

Comment: @BradPitcher, I see. Using `patch.object(foo, 'wait')`, you need to wait long time depending on the time you specified (`0.5` in the example). So it's not recommended.

Comment: @BradPitcher, Try `patch.object(threading.Event, 'wait', lambda *args: time.sleep(0.000001))`

Comment: Thanks @falsetru that looks great. However, I already implemented my tests with the 'wait' patch and I think it will be fine for my use case since my wait times are all short. I also use a contextmanager to make it easy to reuse this code like: `with wait_for_thread(mock): bar()`

https://github.com/orcasgit/python-misfit/blob/master/tests/__init__.py#L9